Asking for author of a short story "The postman and the old woman"
I've just read a touching short story "The postman and the old woman". Strangely, I can't find the name of writer anywhere. I think it's from "Chicken soup for the soul" series but there's too many books. Do anyone know who writes this story? I have some problem with copyright so having the author name will solve it.
Until now, there're two websites that post this story:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/unknown-undefined-relationships-jojan-thomass
https://moralstories26.com/postman-and-old-woman-heart-warming-story/
Thank you in advane.

"Does anyone know who wrote this story?" Presumably someone in India! The two links you supply show slightly different versions, so I would call it an 'anecdote' rather than a literary story.
